# Reduce time on SP2013 Windows Classic to Windows claims convertion

Tags: powershell, migration, claims, classic-mode-auth

We are migrating from SP2010 to SP2013

SP2010 web application is a classic web application ,hence in SP2013 I created a classic web application using PowerShell and mounted the SP2010 DBs.

I ran the below PowerShell script in SP2013 to convert windows classic authentication to windows claims:

```
$wa = get-SPWebApplication "http://WebAppURL:portnumber"  
Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity $wa -From Legacy -To Claims –RetainPermissions –Force
```

This script is executing for more than 24 hours and still yet to be completed.

Is there any way that I can reduce the execution time of this script?

Please note :

The web application has only 1 content DB of around 400 GB and around 7000 users. The content DB got mounted successfully without any error.

Answer (score 0):

By not attaching the nintex config and content Dbs while executing the Convert-SPWebApplication script,I was able to reduce the time for windows classic to windows claims conversion drastically.In my migration scenario,I had to migrate from Windows Classic --> Windows Claims --> ADFS Claims.Since I used a SQL stored procedure to convert nintex users to ADFS Claims,I didnt bother to attach the nintex config and content DBs.